# Can I use a picture commercially if I cannot get ahold of an owner?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons, public-domain

I found a picture on a website through Google Images but the website is just a webpage, a single page with two pictures, no contact information. The second picture doesn't relate at all to the first.

The name of the picture file had the words "CFB Media" in it. So I traced it back to a company called Campus Insiders. I am not sure if it really is theirs, but I emailed them in hopes they might recognize it.

If they don't recognize it as theirs, can I use it? I haven't been able to find it anywhere else besides that webpage with no information.

A quick note also, on Google Images there's a dropdown that lets you filter by license. x:

```
Labeled for reuse with modification
Labeled for reuse
Labeled for noncommercial reuse with modification
Labeled for noncommercial reuse
```

After filtering, the picture looks to be under every single one of these options.

Answer (score 3):

I've found Google's filtering based on licence to not be very reliable, at least not reliable enough to trust from a practical legal perspective.

Using a photo that you don't own the copyright to is a risk. You may be infringing copyright by doing so. The owner may eventually ask you to stop, or they may sue you for damages. Further, some copyright infringement is criminal [17 USC 506](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/506).

In my opinion, it would be unwise to use a work commercially that you don't affirmatively know you have permission to use.